# automatic download pdf after php form submission

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I have the following form

http://www.cubegrfx.com/projects/vnc/bestbuild/wallputtyPDF.html

after the submission and success message getting displayed, I wish to start the pdf download automatically.

the js code follows

```
$('#downloadform').submit(function(){
    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    $("#message").slideUp(250,function() {
        $('#message').hide();
        $('#submit')
            .after('<img src="img/assets/contact-form-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
            .attr('disabled','disabled');
        $.post(action, {
            source: $('#source').val(),
            cname: $('#cname').val(),
            product: $('#product').val(),
            phone: $('#phone').val(),
            mobile: $('#mobile').val(),
            fname: $('#fname').val(),
            lname: $('#lname').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            remarks: $('#remarks').val(),
        },
            function(data){
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                $('#message').slideDown(250);
                $('#downoadform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                if(data.match('success') != null) $('#downloadform').slideUp(850, 'easeInOutExpo');
            }
        );
    });
    return false;
});
```

php code

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$source     = $_POST['source'];
$cname   = $_POST['cname']; 
$product = $_POST['product'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$remarks = $_POST['remarks'];
$verify   = $_POST['verify'];

if(trim($fname) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">You must enter your first name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($lname) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">You must enter your last name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($cname) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">You must enter your company name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($phone) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">You must enter your phone no.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($mobile) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">You must enter your mobile no.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $remarks = stripslashes(remarks);
}

$address = "abc@gmail.com";

$e_subject = $cname . '/' . $fname . ' ' . $lname . ' ' . $source . '.';

$e_source = "Source: $source." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_cname = "Custome Name: $cname." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_product = "Product: $product." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_phone = "Phone No.: $phone." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_mobile = "Mobile: $mobile." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_name = "Contact Person: $fname $lname." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_email = "Email: $email." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_remarks = "Remarks: $remarks.";

$msg = $e_source . $e_cname . $e_product . $e_phone . $e_mobile . $e_name . $e_email . $e_remarks;

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h4 class='highlight'>Thank you <strong>$fname</strong>, you can download the <strong>$product</strong> now.</h4>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

Comment: What PDF ?  I see a form which on completion sends an email.

Comment: I want to start a pdf download once after the thank you message. I don't know the code. Could you help me with the code for the same @KraangPrime